# CSS Alignment Woes

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment

I'm (needless to say) relatively new to CSS3 and I'm having trouble with aligning content.

I have a page with a jQuery UI Tabs module in it. When I display it on the page, it comes out looking like this:

[image]

**EDIT** I know it's a terrible screenshot, but I'll just say, the Tab box is left-aligned on the page.

I've tried to use the `text-align` property on the `<td>` and the `<div>` containing the content, I even got so desperate I tried the HTML `<center>` tag, all to no avail.

Does anyone have a sure-fire way of centering content with CSS?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What's the (x)html look like when the tab box is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're HTML looks like, but you could try something like:

```
<div style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
    ... tabs
</div>
```

Comment: `margin-left` and `margin-right` did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: Woot!  My first answer and it was accepted.  Glad I could help!